# Export a tex file file from python script: "TypeError: a float is required"

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, latex

this is the content to write in a tex file:

```
content=r'''\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for much better looking tables
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty} 

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]\caption{Common Prediction}
\centering
\input{common%(index)s}
\end{table}     

\end{document}
'''
```

i want to replace 'index' with a integger value. 
When i write:

```
with open(directoryPath + os.sep +'commonTables3.tex','w') as f:
    f.write(content%({'index':str(3)}))
```

i have the follow error:

```
f.write(content%({'index':str(3)}))
TypeError: a float is required
```

i don't understand where is my mistake. I try to change '%(index)s' in '%(index)d' (and 'index':str(3) in 'index':3) but i still have the same error. 
thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your text contains another `%` character (in third line). Since the first non-space character after `%` is `f`, it is interpreted as `%f` (ie. float format). You want to either escape this occurence of `%` by doubling it (`%%`) or use `format` method instead of `%` operator.